# Arrow down notation with sets

Tags: probability-theory, notation

I am reading [Probability for Statistics and Machine Learning](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441996336).

I have trouble understanding the arrow notation (similar to [Knuth's arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation)) in the following definition:

> **Theorem 1.1.** Let $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset A_3 \supset \cdots$ be an infinite family of subsets of a sample space $\Omega$ such that $A_n \downarrow A$. Then, $P(A_n) \rightarrow P(A)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I have looked for this notation with relation to sets but I wasn't able to understand its meaning in this context.

Comment: This means $\bigcap_{n\geq 1} A_n = A$.

Comment: Thanks @GabrielRomon. Could you put it as answer? Additionally, does the $\uparrow$ indicate union in a similar way? Thanks

Comment: Yes, if the inclusions are reversed, i.e. $A_1\subset A_2\subset A_3\subset \ldots$ , then $A_n \uparrow A$ means $\bigcup_{n\geq 1} A_n = A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means “sequence of sets $A_n$ decreases to set $A$”: there exists set $A$ that is subset of all $A_n$. For example, $A_n = \left[-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}\right]$ decreases to $A=\{0\}$.